# Can't run ruby command on windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows-10

Recently I am trying to install Ruby on my Windows 10. After the installation process whenever I am trying to run any ruby command such as to check the version of Ruby, I command `ruby -v` and I got Access denied notifications.

For better purpose I am giving the screenshot of the problem I am facing:

[image]

PS: I am using rubyinstaller-2.4.1-2-x64 to install Ruby.

Comment: To access Ruby, go to the Windows menu, click All Programs, scroll down to Ruby, and click “Start Command Prompt with Ruby”. A command prompt terminal will open. If you type ruby -v

Comment: if you use a 32bit windows, use the x86 installer